# Merge two different array based on same key

Tags: php, merge

I have 2 different arrays

First is

```
(int) 0 => [
        'id' => (int) 1,
        'file_name' => 'test',
        'imported_by' => 'John',
        'valid_to' => (float) 1767225600000
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'id' => (int) 2,
        'file_name' => null,
        'imported_by' => 'John',
        'valid_to' => (float) 1767225600000
    ],
```

Second one is

```
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Product) {
        'id' => (int) 1,
        'product_cat' => (int) 10,
        'product_type' => (int) 1,
        'average....
```

I have to push first one into second one based on same key

it shoud look like this one

```
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Product) {
        'id' => (int) 1,
        'product_category_id' => (int) 10,
        'product_vessel_id' => (int) 1,
        'average' => test;
        //content from first array
        'file_name' => 'test',
        'imported_by' => 'John',
        'valid_to' => (float) 1767225600000
```

I have tryied with 
array_merge_recursive($firstArray,$secondArray); but that mean adding elements on the end of firstArray

Comment: you'll probably need a custom merger function

Comment: You are saying you want to cast the first array as an object and merge objects with the same key?  Alternatively, cast the second array as an array, and after merging cast the whole thing as an object?

Comment: I have to merge first array to second (if exists) if not I still need data from second array... so like push to array where id (first_array) == id (second_array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array1 = array(...);
$array2 = array(...);

foreach ( $array1 as $element ) {
  foreach ( $array2 as $object ) {
    if ( $object->id == $element['id'] ) {
         $object->filename = $element['filename'];
         $object->imported_by = $element['imported_by'];
         $object->valid_to = $element['valid_to'];
         break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I want, I have a little bit change code but it works...
@RST thx

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$result = array();
$array_one=array(0 => array('id' =>  1,
        'file_name' => 'test',
        'imported_by' => 'John',
        'valid_to' => 1767225600000),

    1 => array(
        'id' =>  2,
        'file_name' => "",
        'imported_by' => 'John',
        'valid_to' => 1767225600000)



        );


$array_seond=   array(
                    0 => array(
                                'id' =>  1,
                        'product_cat' =>  10,
                        'product_type' =>  1,
                        'average' => 'test'
                    )
                );  


    echo "<pre>";




//print_r($result);

    foreach($array_seond as $key => $value){
                foreach($array_one as $value_second ){

                    if($value['id']==$value_second['id']){
                        $result[$key] =array_merge($array_seond[$key],$value_second);

                    }

                }

    }


    print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function merge_two_arrays($array1,$array2) {
        $data = array();
        $arrayAB = array_merge($array1,$array2);
        foreach ($arrayAB as $value) {
          $id = $value['id'];
          if (!isset($data[$id])) {
            $data[$id] = array();
          }
          $data[$id] = array_merge($data[$id],$value);
        }
        return $data;
      }

    $master_array = merge_two_arrays($array1,$array2);
```